# Labeling a line in a flalign* enviroment

Tags: equations, formatting, align, labels

I would like to label the last line of this computation (and several longer ones), so I may use them as equations, like so:

[image: eq]

```
\begin{flalign*}
\Gamma^{l}_{js}P^{j}Q^{s} &= \frac{1}{2}(\Gamma^{l}_{js}(P+Q)^{j}(P+Q)^{s} - \Gamma^{l}_{js}P^{j}P^{s} -\Gamma^{l}_{js}Q^{j}Q^{s})= & \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(f(x,P+Q)(P+Q)^{l} - f(x,Q)Q^{l} - f(x,P)P^{l})\label{eq31}
\end{flalign*}
```

I've tried to do this with a combination of the equation and split environments, but without success. I would like:

1. The first line in the chain to be left-aligned (this is optional)
2. The following lines to have aligned "=" with the first "=" in the first line
3. The last line to have a label at the end of it, so it can be referenced

So far I've only been able to achieve 1. and 2., but not 3. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `flalign` (nostar) and add `\notag` to each line that you want to have unnumbered. Another possibility, as you seem to have a single alignment column: with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` and the `aligned` environment

Comment: that's the thing. I don't need an ordinary number. I need something I can use /ref with.

Comment: With `\notag` except for a single line, this single line can be referenced. But I think the other solution is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `fleqn` from `nccmath` and `aligned[b]` nested in `equation`. I also repplcad the  fractionary coefficient witha medium-sized fraction (also from `nccmath` which looks better in my opinion.

The `fleqn` environment makes locally equations start at the left margin; an optional arguments gives the possibility to set  at what distance from the (text) left margin equations start – default is `0pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent  We denote $ \Gamma^{l}_{js}$ as a shorthand for $ \Gamma^{l}_{js}(g, m)$
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
  \Gamma^{l}_{js}P^{j}Q^{s} &= \mfrac{1}{2}\bigl(\Gamma^{l}_{js}(P+Q)^{j}(P+Q)^{s} - \Gamma^{l}_{js}P^{j}P^{s} -\Gamma^{l}_{js}Q^{j}Q^{s}\bigr)=  \\
&=\mfrac{1}{2}\bigl(f(x,P+Q)(P+Q)^{l} - f(x,Q)Q^{l} - f(x,P)P^{l}\bigr)\label{eq31}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't install nccmath because the MiKTeX package repository is currently offline. I will accept the answer once I check the code tomorrow.

Comment: You can change repository with MiKTeX console  (Settings button).

Comment: It's a more general problem: 
https://miktex.org/alert/update-problem-7231
but the github ticket says it will be fixed tommorow

Comment: You can download it directly from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages) and use a local package repository. You just have to download `ncctools.tar.lzma` and  5 complementary files (for a valid repository: `pr.ini, files.csv.lzma, miktex-zzdbi-2.9.tar.lzma` (i=1,2,3).

Comment: Code worked as specified. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any command to adjust the default space between lines? It seems wider than between ordinary line-breaks.

Comment: I think this is due to the fractions on both lines. This being said, the interline spacind in amsmath environments is controlled by the value of `\jot` (defaults to 3pt), which can be changed after begin{document}<. You also have the `\spreadlines` environment from `mathtools` for local modifications.